# Animated mesh has incorrect transforms when exported to Unity

Tags: export, unity

I am exporting a model to Unity 3d. Some parts of the model appear rotated 180/90 degrees. I have tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and resetting the location/scale/rotation but to no effect.

I am directly using the .blend file in the Unity Asset window; without using any export file (dae, fbx etc).

Just to mention that the models transforms are ok when in scene view in unity; until I press the play button that is...

In blender (first image) and in Unity:

[image: In Blender]
[image: In Unity]

You can download the model [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=04385295535467978681) to check for any problems.

Comment: I don't think you applied the scale/rotation for all of them. Make sure you do this. A -> Ctrl + A. Also try removing the items from the group.

Comment: I did, but i lost the animation on the moving parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, it is a bad idea to animate meshes for use in other applications, there is alot to take into consideration such as world coordinates etc. After animating these, you have very limited control over the mesh in terms of applying transforms or even modifying the mesh later.

Solution, use bones to rig and animate the windmill after applying transforms to the separate parts. Example [file with rigged windmill](http://pasteall.org/blend/27081) and applied scale and location. By making use of bones to handle the animation, your hard suface model can now be manipulated without the risk of breaking anything else.

[image]

Comment: Makes sense now. I was of the impression that the animations should be smoothly exported into unity. Will incorporate your suggestions into my current workflow. Thanks...!

Comment: Yikes! this one is dead too! are there any living remnants of the pastall era?