# Tank asset's meshes disordered in Unity

Tags: unity

I recently followed along a tutorial to create a tank in blender, but whenever I try to import the asset into Unity it is in complete shambles. I'll attach screenshots on how it looks in Blender and then in Unity after the import, any ideas why this happens?

[image: How it looks in Blender]

[image: How it looks in Unity]

Comment: You need to apply the rotation and scale. Use `Ctrl + A`. Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7317/12

Comment: This resolved by issue, you should make this an answer post so I can thumb it up!

Side note: I got an issue with some faces disappearing in Unity, but after selecting the body, going into edit mode, Mesh -> Normals -> Recalculate outside, and re-importing I got them back!

Comment: See a detailed answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/messed-up-blender-models-when-exporting-to-unity3d?noredirect=1&lq=1) as to why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the models were transformed in world space (Object mode) in Blender. To fix, you need to make everything have a common origin or space by resetting their transforms to `1`. Otherwise whatever package imports these will try to fit it into their world using said transforms. To fix, simply apply the rotation and scale and maybe even the location as well with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.

Related [Animated mesh has incorrect transforms when exported to Unity](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7317/12)

Comment: I couldn't find an exact duplicate of this question, if anyone does, please link it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to fix rotation and scale of the model before exporting It.

Comment: I think it would be useful if you could give details as to *how* a user is meant to 'fix' rotation and scale.

Comment: please do [edit] your answer and make it more fleshed out, and helpful with steps on how to solve the OP's problem. As it is now your one line is really just a one line suggestion. (that is likely to get downvoted)